# How to connect to hyperv guest machine by rdp through internet?

Tags: routing, rdp, internet

I installed hyperv and some client machines. Now i need to connect to any of client machine and host by using rdp through internet. [This instruction](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network) tell me what i need to configure port forwarding on router, but i haven't router - cable pluged into server.

I suppose, I need configure some software to forward some ports connection to guests machine ips. For example, request to 3333 port route to 192.168.1.2:3389 and request to 3334 port route to 192.168.1.3:3389.

So, does my assumption correct or how can I accomplish rdp connection through internet?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a terrible setup you ahve - one driven by not knowing what is around and listening to bad advice.

here is what I did:

- I have a Hyper-V instance that runs REMOTE DESKTOP GATEWAY (Terminal Services Gateway) - it is a standard windows service. It has a public IP.
- I can then connect to i via RDP client with the IP (domain name) as GATWAY, and it forwards the request to the end machine.

Works like a charm, can limit feaures per user and... also forces RDP obver HTTP which makes it easier to conenct through some firewalls at clients. This is the technology made for that issue - port forwarding is a clumsy workaround mostly used by people (for RDP) not able to read the documentation and thus being ignorant towards it's existence.

http://www.petri.co.il/images/ts-gateway.png

explains how it works then.